# fineuploader file list empty

Tags: java, struts-1, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader within a struts system but am having trouble getting the file list in the server code.

My jsp contains the following code:

```
    $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: '/NRGI/act_MultiPhotoUpload.do'
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: '/uploads'
        },
        retry: {
           enableAuto: true
        }
    });
```

with the following div near the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
```

The action actMultiPhotoUpload points to a class via the struts.config.xml file:

```
<action path="/act_MultiPhotoUpload" name="FileUploadForm" scope="request" validate="true"
   type="com.solarcentury.nrgi.document.action.MultiUploadAction"
   input="/D5_PhotoLibrary.jsp">
</action>
```

The class MultiUploadAction is taken from your UploadReceiver and is as follows:

```
public class MultiUploadAction extends Action {

    static Static_Env_Object seo = new Static_Env_Object();
    private String UPLOAD_NOT_ALLOWED = "exe";
    private EnvUtils eu;




//  JUST FOR TESTING
    private static final File UPLOAD_DIR = new File("Test/uploads");
    private static File TEMP_DIR = new File("Test/uploadsTemp");
    private static String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
    private static int SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    public ActionForward perform(ActionMapping mapping,
            ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String sId = session.getId();
        eu = new EnvUtils(seo.get_Env_Name(), this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        /* **************************************** */
        /* * The code for the session timeout check */
        /* **************************************** */
        if (session.getAttribute("SESS_User") == null) {

            eu.log("NO SESSION", "Session timed out...");

            return (mapping.findForward("globaltimeout"));
        }

        UserObject suo = new UserObj_Util(session).get_SessUser();
        WebAlertMessages wam = new WebAlertMessages(request, suo.get_Language_ID());
        DemonUtil du = new DemonUtil(seo.get_Env_Name());
        // DateUtils dateUtil = new DateUtils();

        RequestParser requestParser = null;

        boolean isIframe = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null || !request.getHeader("X-Requested-With").equals("XMLHttpRequest");
        try
        {
//            resp.setContentType(isIframe ? "text/html" : "text/plain");
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setStatus(SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE);


//            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.130.118:8080");
//            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
//            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");


            if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
            {
                MultipartUploadParser multipartUploadParser = new MultipartUploadParser(request, TEMP_DIR, request.getSession().getServletContext());
                requestParser = RequestParser.getInstance(request, multipartUploadParser);
                writeFileForMultipartRequest(requestParser);
                writeResponse(response.getWriter(), requestParser.generateError() ? "Generated error" : null, isIframe, false, requestParser);
            }
            else
            {
                requestParser = RequestParser.getInstance(request, null);


                //handle POST delete file request
                if (requestParser.getMethod() != null
                        && requestParser.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE"))
                {
                    String uuid = requestParser.getUuid();
                    handleDeleteFileRequest(uuid, response);
                }
                else
                {
                    writeFileForNonMultipartRequest(request, requestParser);
                    writeResponse(response.getWriter(), requestParser.generateError() ? "Generated error" : null, isIframe, false, requestParser);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            eu.log("UploadReceiver","Problem handling upload request" + e);
            if (e instanceof MultiUploadAction.MergePartsException)
            {
                writeResponse(response.getWriter(), e.getMessage(), isIframe, true, requestParser);
            }
            else
            {
                writeResponse(response.getWriter(), e.getMessage(), isIframe, false, requestParser);
            }
        }

        return (new ActionForward(mapping.getInput()));
    }
```

And I use the MultipartUploadParser, RequestParser from the server java examples on the website.

When I step through the code, how ever many files I select to upload, the file list is always empty. Obviously I am doing something stupid here, but would appreciate any guidance please.

I have seen a similar support question where the asker was having trouble getting the filelist, also using struts, but there wasn't an answer against the question

Added on 14/11/2013

The full code is as follows:

The full listing of MultiUploadAction.java is as follows:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.solarcentury.nrgi.document.action;

/**
 *
 * @author Roy
 */
import DemonWeb.DmForms.FileUploadForm;

import DemonWeb.DmLogic.DemonUtil;
import DemonWeb.DmLogic.Project;
import DemonWeb.DmSession.Static_Env_Object;
import DemonWeb.DmSession.UserObj_Util;
import DemonWeb.DmSession.UserObject;
import DemonWeb.DmSession.WebAlertMessages;
import DemonWeb.Utils.EnvUtils;
import com.solarcentury.nrgi.document.bean.Document;

import com.solarcentury.nrgi.document.logic.DocumentController;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile;

/**
 *
 * @author ajantham
 */
public class MultiUploadAction extends Action {

    static Static_Env_Object seo = new Static_Env_Object();
    private String UPLOAD_NOT_ALLOWED = "exe";
    private EnvUtils eu;




//  JUST FOR TESTING
    private static final File UPLOAD_DIR = new File("uploads");
    private static File TEMP_DIR = new File("uploadsTemp");
    private static String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
    private static int SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    public ActionForward perform(ActionMapping mapping,
            ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String sId = session.getId();
        eu = new EnvUtils(seo.get_Env_Name(), this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        /* **************************************** */
        /* * The code for the session timeout check */
        /* **************************************** */
        if (session.getAttribute("SESS_User") == null) {

            eu.log("NO SESSION", "Session timed out...");

            return (mapping.findForward("globaltimeout"));
        }

        UserObject suo = new UserObj_Util(session).get_SessUser();
        WebAlertMessages wam = new WebAlertMessages(request, suo.get_Language_ID());
        DemonUtil du = new DemonUtil(seo.get_Env_Name());
        // DateUtils dateUtil = new DateUtils();

        RequestParser requestParser = null;

        boolean isIframe = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null || !request.getHeader("X-Requested-With").equals("XMLHttpRequest");
        try
        {
//            resp.setContentType(isIframe ? "text/html" : "text/plain");
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setStatus(SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE);


//            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.130.118:8080");
//            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
//            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
            {
                MultipartUploadParser multipartUploadParser = new MultipartUploadParser(request, TEMP_DIR, request.getSession().getServletContext());
                requestParser = RequestParser.getInstance(request, multipartUploadParser);
                writeFileForMultipartRequest(requestParser);
                writeResponse(response.getWriter(), requestParser.generateError() ? "Generated error" : null, isIframe, false, requestParser);
            }
            else
            {
                requestParser = RequestParser.getInstance(request, null);


                //handle POST delete file request
                if (requestParser.getMethod() != null
                        && requestParser.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE"))
                {
                    String uuid = requestParser.getUuid();
                    handleDeleteFileRequest(uuid, response);
                }
                else
                {
                    writeFileForNonMultipartRequest(request, requestParser);
                    writeResponse(response.getWriter(), requestParser.generateError() ? "Generated error" : null, isIframe, false, requestParser);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            eu.log("UploadReceiver","Problem handling upload request" + e);
            if (e instanceof MultiUploadAction.MergePartsException)
            {
                writeResponse(response.getWriter(), e.getMessage(), isIframe, true, requestParser);
            }
            else
            {
                writeResponse(response.getWriter(), e.getMessage(), isIframe, false, requestParser);
            }
        }

        return (new ActionForward(mapping.getInput()));
    }


    public void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        String uuid = req.getPathInfo().replaceAll("/", "");


        handleDeleteFileRequest(uuid, resp);
    }


    private void handleDeleteFileRequest(String uuid, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(UPLOAD_DIR, uuid));


        if (new File(UPLOAD_DIR, uuid).exists())
        {
            eu.log("UploadReceiver","couldn't find or delete " + uuid);
        }
        else
        {
            eu.log("UploadReceiver","deleted " + uuid);
        }


        resp.setStatus(SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE);
//        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }


    private void writeFileForNonMultipartRequest(HttpServletRequest req, RequestParser requestParser) throws Exception
    {
        File dir = new File(UPLOAD_DIR, requestParser.getUuid());
        dir.mkdirs();


        String contentLengthHeader = req.getHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH);
        long expectedFileSize = Long.parseLong(contentLengthHeader);


        if (requestParser.getPartIndex() >= 0)
        {
            writeFile(req.getInputStream(), new File(dir, requestParser.getUuid() + "_" + String.format("%05d", requestParser.getPartIndex())), null);


            if (requestParser.getTotalParts()-1 == requestParser.getPartIndex())
            {
                File[] parts = getPartitionFiles(dir, requestParser.getUuid());
                File outputFile = new File(dir, requestParser.getFilename());
                for (File part : parts)
                {
                    mergeFiles(outputFile, part);
                }


                assertCombinedFileIsVaid(requestParser.getTotalFileSize(), outputFile, requestParser.getUuid());
                deletePartitionFiles(dir, requestParser.getUuid());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            writeFile(req.getInputStream(), new File(dir, requestParser.getFilename()), expectedFileSize);
        }
    }




    private void writeFileForMultipartRequest(RequestParser requestParser) throws Exception
    {
        File dir = new File(UPLOAD_DIR, requestParser.getUuid());
        dir.mkdirs();


        if (requestParser.getPartIndex() >= 0)
        {
            writeFile(requestParser.getUploadItem().getInputStream(), new File(dir, requestParser.getUuid() + "_" + String.format("%05d", requestParser.getPartIndex())), null);


            if (requestParser.getTotalParts()-1 == requestParser.getPartIndex())
            {
                File[] parts = getPartitionFiles(dir, requestParser.getUuid());
                File outputFile = new File(dir, requestParser.getOriginalFilename());
                for (File part : parts)
                {
                    mergeFiles(outputFile, part);
                }


                assertCombinedFileIsVaid(requestParser.getTotalFileSize(), outputFile, requestParser.getUuid());
                deletePartitionFiles(dir, requestParser.getUuid());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            writeFile(requestParser.getUploadItem().getInputStream(), new File(dir, requestParser.getFilename()), null);
        }
    }


    private void assertCombinedFileIsVaid(int totalFileSize, File outputFile, String uuid) throws MultiUploadAction.MergePartsException
    {
        if (totalFileSize != outputFile.length())
        {
            deletePartitionFiles(UPLOAD_DIR, uuid);
            outputFile.delete();
            throw new MultiUploadAction.MergePartsException("Incorrect combined file size!");
        }


    }




    private static class PartitionFilesFilter implements FilenameFilter
    {
        private String filename;
        PartitionFilesFilter(String filename)
        {
            this.filename = filename;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file, String s)
        {
            return s.matches(Pattern.quote(filename) + "_\\d+");
        }
    }


    private static File[] getPartitionFiles(File directory, String filename)
    {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles(new MultiUploadAction.PartitionFilesFilter(filename));
        Arrays.sort(files);
        return files;
    }


    private static void deletePartitionFiles(File directory, String filename)
    {
        File[] partFiles = getPartitionFiles(directory, filename);
        for (File partFile : partFiles)
        {
            partFile.delete();
        }
    }


    private File mergeFiles(File outputFile, File partFile) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true);


        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(partFile);


            try
            {
                IOUtils.copy(fis, fos);
            }
            finally
            {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
        }


        return outputFile;
    }


    private File writeFile(InputStream in, File out, Long expectedFileSize) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;


        try
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(out);


            IOUtils.copy(in, fos);


            if (expectedFileSize != null)
            {
                Long bytesWrittenToDisk = out.length();
                if (!expectedFileSize.equals(bytesWrittenToDisk))
                {
                    eu.log("UploadReceiver","Expected file {} to be {} bytes; file on disk is {} bytes " + new Object[] { out.getAbsolutePath(), expectedFileSize, 1 });
                    out.delete();
                    throw new IOException(String.format("Unexpected file size mismatch. Actual bytes %s. Expected bytes %s.", bytesWrittenToDisk, expectedFileSize));
                }
            }


            return out;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
        }
    }


    private void writeResponse(PrintWriter writer, String failureReason, boolean isIframe, boolean restartChunking, RequestParser requestParser)
    {
        if (failureReason == null)
        {
//            if (isIframe)
//            {
//                writer.print("{\"success\": true, \"uuid\": \"" + requestParser.getUuid() + "\"}<script src=\"http://192.168.130.118:8080/client/js/iframe.xss.response.js\"></script>");
//            }
//            else
//            {
                writer.print("{\"success\": true}");
//            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (restartChunking)
            {
                writer.print("{\"error\": \"" + failureReason + "\", \"reset\": true}");
            }
            else
            {
//                if (isIframe)
//                {
//                    writer.print("{\"error\": \"" + failureReason + "\", \"uuid\": \"" + requestParser.getUuid() + "\"}<script src=\"http://192.168.130.118:8080/client/js/iframe.xss.response.js\"></script>");
//                }
//                else
//                {


                    writer.print("{\"error\": \"" + failureReason + "\"}");
//                }
            }
        }
    }


    private class MergePartsException extends Exception
    {
        MergePartsException(String message)
        {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The full source of MultipartUploadParser.java is as follows:

```
package com.solarcentury.nrgi.document.action;


import DemonWeb.DmSession.Static_Env_Object;
import DemonWeb.Utils.EnvUtils;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.FileCleanerCleanup;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaningTracker;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.*;


public class MultipartUploadParser
{
//        final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipartUploadParser.class);
        static Static_Env_Object seo = new Static_Env_Object();
        private EnvUtils eu;

        private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


        private List<FileItem> files = new ArrayList<FileItem>();


        // fileItemsFactory is a field (even though it's scoped to the constructor) to prevent the
        // org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.FileCleanerCleanup thread from attempting to delete the
        // temp file before while it is still being used.
        //
        // FileCleanerCleanup uses a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue to delete the temp file when the FileItemsFactory marker object is GCed
        private DiskFileItemFactory fileItemsFactory;


        public MultipartUploadParser(HttpServletRequest request, File repository, ServletContext context) throws Exception
        {
                this.eu = new EnvUtils(seo.get_Env_Name(), "MultipartUploadParser " + "1.0.0.0");

                if (!repository.exists() && !repository.mkdirs())
                {
                        throw new IOException("Unable to mkdirs to " + repository.getAbsolutePath());
                }


                fileItemsFactory = setupFileItemFactory(repository, context);


        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemsFactory);
        List<FileItem> formFileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);


                parseFormFields(formFileItems);


                if (files.isEmpty())
                {
                        eu.log("MultipartUploadParser","No files were found when processing the request. Debugging info follows");


                        writeDebugInfo(request);


                        throw new FileUploadException("No files were found when processing the request.");
                }
                else
                {
                        writeDebugInfo(request);
                }
        }


        private DiskFileItemFactory setupFileItemFactory(File repository, ServletContext context)
        {
                DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                factory.setSizeThreshold(DiskFileItemFactory.DEFAULT_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
                factory.setRepository(repository);


                FileCleaningTracker pTracker = FileCleanerCleanup.getFileCleaningTracker(context);
                factory.setFileCleaningTracker(pTracker);

                return factory;
        }


        private void writeDebugInfo(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
                eu.log("MultipartUploadParser","-- POST HEADERS --");
                for (String header : Collections.list((Enumeration<String>) request.getHeaderNames()))
                {
                        eu.log("MultipartUploadParser", header + "header " + request.getHeader(header));
                }


                eu.log("MultipartUploadParser","-- POST PARAMS --");
                for (String key : params.keySet())
                {
                        eu.log("MultipartUploadParser", key + " key " + params.get(key));
                }
        }


        private void parseFormFields(List<FileItem> items) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
                for (FileItem item : items)
                {
                        if (item.isFormField())
                        {
                                String key = item.getFieldName();
                                String value = item.getString("UTF-8");
                                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(key))
                                {
                                        params.put(key, StringUtils.defaultString(value));
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                files.add(item);
                        }
                }
        }


        public Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
                return params;
        }


        public List<FileItem> getFiles()
        {
                if (files.isEmpty())
                {
                        throw new RuntimeException("No FileItems exist.");
                }


                return files;
        }


        public FileItem getFirstFile()
        {
                if (files.isEmpty())
                {
                        throw new RuntimeException("No FileItems exist.");
                }


                return files.iterator().next();
        }
}
```

MultiUploadAction decides that the request isMultipartContent and so calls MultipartUploadParser. This class successfully
checks the directory structure and then uses its method ParseFormFields to buld up a list of files. 
However it does not find any files or form fields, and so on line 62 of MultipartUploadParser files.isEmpty() is true,
and so an exception is thrown (line 70)

It doesn't matter how many files I select in the client, the file list is always empty.

Many thanks for your help in this - much appreciated

Comment: Btw your code is related to Struts1. I'll change the tag, but if you can, you change the framework !

Comment: Sorry about that Andrea

Comment: Please show the exact code that is failing and be clear what specific line or lines are problematic for you.  The issue is most definitely in your server code, but if you don't provide all of your code and provide more specific information about the trouble areas, there is little that can be done.   Perhaps something on your server is parsing the request and ripping out the payload before it hits the code you have provided here.  It's not clear what "file list" you are talking about.  What specific calls are you making, what result are you seeing, and what result are you expecting?

Comment: Many thanks for the Comment Ray - I'll come back with more details as requested, tomorrow

Comment: I have added the full code to the above question and have tried to explain in a little more details where it is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I ran into this same problem. In my implementation I had tried to adapt the example endpoint code into my Spring MVC project.  I discovered that the Spring MVC framework was actually calling the same Apache ServletFileUpload.parseRequest BEFORE passing the request to my controller and detecting the multipart, fetching the params, etc. The framework was parsing the multipart request despite whether I was using MutlipartHttpServlet request, or simply HttpServletRequest as my signature for the controller method.  When my code in the MultipartUploadParser hit ServletFileUpload.parseRequest again, this time it returned an empty List because they had already been parsed.

The endpoint example code in the git repo for Fine Uploader works as it is, it was just my adaptation with Spring MVC that didn't work.

Comment: I have to correct my post.  The issue isn't specific to the Content-Disposition, as I have examined HTTP multipart posts for file uploads from other libraries, and they use "form-data" as well.  But there is something in the construction of the post that causes apache's ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(request) to fail getting FileItem objects from the request.  I'm trying to research that now.

Comment: Further testing showed that if you are using a framework, such as Spring MVC, Apache's ServletFileUpload.parseRequest is called by the framework BEFORE it is handed to your controller code, and if you call it again, it will return an empty list for FileItems.  In my case I had to refactor my controller code to use Spring's MultipartHttpServletRequest correctly.  So, no problem with HTTP post from Fine Uploader, just a matter of server side programming.

Comment: "Problem is that the js for Fine Uploader puts the file payload into a form-data element in the HTTP request". Fine Uploader doesn't do this - this is how form submits actually work. By default, upload requests are multipart encoded. If your server code is choking on this request, then the issue is definitely with your server code.